# Wordpress + python integration

Tags: plugins, php, python

For the sake of simplicity let me give you an idea of what I would like to accomplish. I have a website with `paidmembershipspro`. I also have a python code on a separate server, which is generating news.

I would like to have a page that will consist of all the links to the articles, which will only be shown to members of a particular class (I think PMpro's shortcodes should do the job).

My first idea was to create a custom code on PHP, which will generate all that, but I have not found a way to execute PHP on a particular place on the page (or maybe PHP is not the best option at all).

If someone knows how to tackle this, please feel free to add your suggestions, every bit helps.

Comment: WordPress has a REST API that can be used to create content: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ However using a REST API from Python is something you would need to ask about on a Python development forum, as it would not be on topic here.

Comment: If you're unsure how to insert PHP into a WP page then you should ask how to do that. There are 2 answers, shortcodes or server rendered blocks. If its the entire page then a page template may suffice but will have less flexibility. Otherwise it looks like you've fallen into the classic X Y problem

Comment: @JacobPeattie I am quite familiar with python, so I think this part will not be a problem. I will definitely look into this, thank you.

Comment: @TomJNowell, you are right, the question is more about inserting the code (I will try to make it more clear in the edit). Could you, please, elaborate on how shortcodes and SR blocks (doesn't have to be PHP btw)? I am not too familiar with WordPress, so I don't know what will be the best approach.

Comment: @user9102437 Are you using the block editor? Shortcode ([docu](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/)) is the "old way" that will still work. Dynamic Blocks ([docu](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/)) are probably a bit more difficult to implement but will look more fancy in the editor.

Comment: @kero thanks, shortcodes worked perfectly for me. Haven't implemented the integration with python, but this is just a question of time.

Comment: integrating python into PHP _might_ be possible, but it will be very hacky and unreliable, _and it will not save you time_, it's more likely to occupy several weeks of time just figuring out how it will all work. It would be much easier to do it in pure PHP or pure Python. It would actually be much easier to integrate Node as there's a PHP extension called runkit. It's probably it would need some kind of socket based communication or iframes